# C++/Cli add callback to a managed Action<T1,T2> object

Tags: c#, delegates, c++-cli

In a c# class, I have the following :

```
public class Myclass
{
  public Action<string, string> MyDelegate { get; set;}

  public void CallingAction()
  {
    MyDelegate("string1", "string2");
  }
}
```

In C++/Cli, I want to add a new function to the delegate.

```
public ref class MyCliClass
{
  public :
  MyCliClass()
  {
    MyClass^ myClassInstance = gcnew MyClass();
    MyCliDelegate^ myDelegateInstance = gcnew MyCliDelegate(this, &MyCliClass::FunctionToCall);
    myClassInstance->MyDelegate += myDelegateInstance;
  }

  void FunctionToCall(string^ string1, string^ string2)
  {
    // Some stuff to do
  }

  private :
  void delegate MyCliDelegate(string^,string^);
}
```

This gives me the error :

```
error C3365: operator '+' : differing operands of type 'System::Action<T1, T2> ^' and 'MyCliClass::FunctionToCall^'
```

How can I simply add "FunctionToCall" to the C# Delegate so when "CallingAction" is called, "FunctionToCall" is also called ?

Thank you

**EDIT/ANSWER**
Here is the new Cli/Class

```
public ref class MyCliClass
{
  public :
  MyCliClass()
  {
    MyClass^ myClassInstance = gcnew MyClass();
    myClassInstance->MyDelegate += gcnew Action<string^,string^>^(this, &MyCliClass::FunctionToCall);
  }

  void FunctionToCall(string^ string1, string^ string2)
  {
    // Some stuff to do
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Equivalent delegate types are not convertible.
You need to declare your delegate instance as an `Action<string^, string^>^`.